# Unable to connect to cloud sql on GCP

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect to cloud sql hosted in gcp from eclipse, not able to do so. I have whitelisted my ip using the connection settings on cloud sql instance. I have added the driver also in eclipse for mysql.

I think I am making mistake in constructing the connection string. Please refer below details.

```
connectionName: abc-dev:europe-west1:abc-instance
```

So in connection section

```
database: abc-dev:europe-west1:abc-instance
url: jdbc:mysql://35.233.100.100:3306/abcInsoles
user: root
password: xyz123
```

It throws exception:
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

I am running it from local.

Can you throw some insights?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "database" value is incorrect - this is the name of the database on the instance itself (not the instance's connection string).

Since you are using Java, you may be interested in the [Cloud SQL JDBC Socket Factory](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory) - it allows you to connect to the Cloud SQL instance without whitelisting an IP.

Comment: ok, got it. Thanks. actually, my requirement is very specific. I want to generate jpa entity class for large db where so many tables are already there. These entities will be generated using eclipse plugins & eclipse is not able to deal with the said connection string mentioned in your github post.

Comment: thanks. Can you guide me how it can be used for node js solutions?